# What is an Oscillator Clock and a System Clock?

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, clock

What are the differences between Oscillator Clock and System Clock? How they are used in a microcontroller?

Comment: A little bit of context would help to explain the difference, like do you mean a specific microcontroller? Otherwise this sounds like it is a homework question, which is either very generic question, or specific to some known MCU.

Answer (score 1):

A system clock is a clock that provides the main timing reference for a system. The term itself tells you how it is used.

An oscillator clock is a clock produced by an oscillator (as opposed to, for example, being provided by an external signal).

An oscillator clock might be used as the system clock, or for any other function that requires a clock signal.

Answer (score 1):

The oscillator is the raw clock source you give to the microcontroller or processor. The system clock is the clock that actually runs the chip.

The difference exists because the system clock is derived from the oscillator. The oscillator might be directly used as the system clock, or it might be run through something like a PLL to change the frequency before being used as the system clock.

There may also be other clocks derived from the system clock.